# Component is rendering twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am following a tutorial and just learned about `useEffect`.
The issue I am having is that I want to get `result.hours[0].is_open_now`. I've discovered that the component renders twice, and since hours is undefined at first, it fails.

Is there a way to make this only run once.

```
const ResultsShowScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const id = navigation.getParam('id');
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState({})

    const getResult = async (id) => {
       const response = await yelp.get(`/${id}`)
       setResult(response.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getResult(id)
     }, [])

    if (!result || result.length <= 0) {
        return null
    }

     const {name, 
            display_address, 
            price,
            display_phone,
            photos,
            review_count,
            rating,
            hours          
        } = result

        if (hours && hours.length > 0 ) {
            const is_open_now = hours[0].is_open_now
            console.log('running')
        } else {
            console.log('nooooo')
        }

    return (
        <View> 

            <Text style={styles.title}>{name}</Text>

            <Text>Price: {price}</Text>
            <Text>Rating: {rating}</Text>
            <Text>Reviews: {review_count}</Text>
            <Text>Phone: {display_phone}</Text>
            <Text>Is Open Now: </Text>
        </View>
    )

}

export default ResultsShowScreen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your code you can not prevent `useEffect` render twice because following [react hook lifecycle](http://If%20you%E2%80%99re%20familiar%20with%20React%20class%20lifecycle%20methods,%20you%20can%20think%20of%20useEffect%20Hook%20as%20componentDidMount,%20componentDidUpdate,%20and%20componentWillUnmount%20combined.),

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

That's mean `useEffect` will be executed after component render the first time (Your code fiirst time is null) and executed more time if the second arg has values.

In your `useEffect`, you call `setState` to set new state and component auto render if state change. So your component will be rendered at least twice.